# VB.NET write to file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, streamwriter

This should be an easy one, but I'm strugling.

I've developed a web page and I'm trying to load values into a text file. I have the asp webform with a textbox and a button. When the button is pressed loads the message from the textbox to the text file.

When debugg it, it appears to work, but I can not see anything written in the file when I open it (or maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?)

When I publish it, it does not work.

Here is the code I'm using

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Both file_name below seem to work
    ' Dim FILE_NAME As String = "TB.txt"
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "..\TB.txt"
    Dim line1 As String

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
    'objWriter.NewLine = True

    line1 = TextBox1.Text

    objWriter.WriteLine(line1)
    'objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)

    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Text written to file")

End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You could try `objWriter.Flush()` immediately before the `Close`. I don't see why it should be necessary, but it can't hurt. Does `line1` contain anything?

Comment: No luck. When published still doesn't work. An I can not find what I write anywhere. Line1 contains the text I enter in Textbox1

Comment: Can you find TB.txt? Do you know where it's actually going? Or are you getting an exception indicating the write failed (which, looking at your code, you should not be getting). Try hard-coding the full file path.

Comment: I tried the following: Dim FILE_NAME As String = "\\ServerName\web\TB.txt" With this I can see that text is loaded in TB.txt when debuggin. But when I publish the site it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to be more precise than "it doesn't work". When debugging, can you find the file TB.txt? Try something really simply, like `FILE_NAME = C:\TB.txt`

Comment: @Selrac - This looks like a security related issue. While running the published site, do you see any exceptions in the Event Log? Does the account under which the website runs, have write permissions to your folder?

Comment: Yes, the following work when debugging: Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\TB.txt", but not when I publish the web site

Comment: I don't think it is a write permision issue. If I use \\ServerName\web\TB.txt it works during debugging, but not when I publish

Comment: @Selrac: Please define "It doesn't work": What exceptions do you get? - what, if anything does happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText(FILE_NAME, TextBox1.Text)
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)

Comment: This works when debbuging, but I'm still facing the problem when publishing it doesn't work and I don't see where the data is being save into unless I hardcode the path

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was created by this line:

```
MsgBox("Text written to file")
```

Once this was removed all worked fine.

Thanks for all the advice and support